# Lazy Loading with Childroutes not working

Tags: angular, nativescript, lazy-loading

I have a propably really simple question, but I just cant figure out what the mistake is I make.

I try to implement Lazy Loading in my Nativescript App.

EDIT: added this little overview for easier understanding:
[image]

app-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes= [
    {path:'', redirectTo: 'auth', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path:'auth', component: AnmeldungComponent},
    {path:'system', loadChildren: '~/app/system/system.module#SystemModule'},
    {path:'settings', component: SettingsComponent}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

system-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "",
        component: ListeSystemComponent,
    },
    { path: "monitorliste", component: ListeMonitorComponent },
    { path: "messwerte/:id", component: DatenMonitordatenComponent },
    {
        path:
            "messwertverlauf/:schwelleAlert/:schwelleGut/:schwelleWarn/:schwelleRichtung/:id",
        component: MesswertverlaufComponent,
    },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule],
})
export class SystemRoutingModule {}
```

I know I am already using `.forChild(routes)` I think it isn't causing any problems or is it?

system.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ListeSystemComponent,
        ListeMonitorComponent,
        DatenMonitordatenComponent,
        MesswertverlaufComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        NativeScriptRouterModule,
        SystemRoutingModule,
        NativeScriptCommonModule,
        SharedModule
    ],
    schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})
export class SystemModule {}
```

Short explanation what the code is for, so maybe you can give some further advice for improvement since I'm very new to all of this.
After the login the user should get redirected to choose a system to display, if he is logged in he should get redirected to the system he was on.

--> first Question: does it make sense to lazily load the monitors (thats whats in a system) or does it make more sense to lazily load the parts after the monitors?  I hope you get my question ^^'

when not using child-routing, I had code like this:

```
this.router.navigate(['/system/monitorliste'], { transition: {name: 'slideLeft'}});
```

now when using child-routing, I tried this:

```
this.router.navigate(['/monitorliste'], { transition: {name: 'slideLeft'}, relativeTo: this.route});
```

but it didn't work as expected...
***EDIT:***
system-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "",
        component: ListeSystemComponent,
        children: [
            { path: "monitorliste", component: ListeMonitorComponent },
            { path: "messwerte/:id", component: DatenMonitordatenComponent },
            {
                path:
                    "messwertverlauf/:schwelleAlert/:schwelleGut/:schwelleWarn/:schwelleRichtung/:id",
                component: MesswertverlaufComponent,
            },
        ],
    },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule],
})
export class SystemRoutingModule {}
```

I can't figure out how to get it working, because currently either I get the error, that `'monitorlist'` can't be found as URL or that I get stuck when choosing a system.

I think there will be some more questions of your side, when trying to help me and I'll try to answer as fast as possible.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use of LazyLoading depends on your project structure. I think the best way is to always have a lazy loaded module for each component. So in best way you should come to this solutuon (also with AuthGuard)

app-routing-module

```
const routes: Routes= [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'system', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'auth', loadChildren: './modules/auth/auth.module#AuthModule'},
  {path: 'system', loadChildren: './modules/system/system.module#SystemModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path: 'settings', loadChildren: './modules/settings/settings.module#SettingsModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

And then for example in your System routing module you should have one main System component and others are his children like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [

  {
    path: '',
    component: ListeSystemComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'monitorliste',
        component: ListeMonitorComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'messwerte/:id',
        component: DatenMonitordatenComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'messwertverlauf/:schwelleAlert/:schwelleGut/:schwelleWarn/:schwelleRichtung/:id',
        component: MesswertverlaufComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule],
})
export class SystemRoutingModule {}
```

In routing you can use "canActiveate" with for example AuthGuard which checks if user isLogged in and only then the default "system" URL is accessible as default url => ''.

Then you can make something similar to System->Monitor routing.

Example of AuthGuard:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from "../shared/auth.service";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    public authService: AuthService,
    public router: Router
  ){ }

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    console.log('AuthGuard check token: ', this.authService.token);

    if(this.authService.token != null){
      return true;
    }  
    else if(this.authService.isLoggedIn == true) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      this.router.navigate(['/sign-in'])
    }
    return false;
  }

}
```

By implementing the guards, you don't even have to use the router.navigate in your components, because you will make the navigation logic with the Guards and Lazy loading.

But if you don't like to use guards, you are able to navigate in components like in this case

```
@Component({...})
class ListeSystemComponent{
  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
   this.goDeeper()
  }

  goDeeper() {
    this.router.navigate(['/monitorliste'], { relativeTo: this.route });
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, I was thinking about adding an AuthGuard aswell. is there anything, that I have to pay attention to when navigating to child-routes since I encountered some difficulties as mantioned above...

Comment: u're welcome. You should be fine, just stick with the module-component-childrencomponent structure which I described. Plus check my edited answer below.

Comment: I have one more question, what do you mean with "you don't even have to use the router.navigate in your components" ? you mean that I can implement all the routing logic in the Guards?

Comment: :-)  ...yes with combination of guards and router modules. By declaring a default path with redirect in each sub-router module and canActivate guard. For example as you have AuthGuard, you can also have SystemGuard, which you can use on your Monitor Module. So in your System Routing Module, your default path (' ') can do Redirect to Monitor Module with canActivate: SystemGuard checker. So the Monitor will be loaded by default, but only if SystemGuard allows it.

Comment: can you have a look at my edited system-routing.module.ts?
Its the part under the EDIT - row :)

Comment: Ok and what is the problem now ?  Your 'monitorliste' component should be available under path .../listesystem/monitorliste

Comment: Check this course about lazy loading. I'm sure you will get it after watching this.
https://codingcat.dev/courses/angularmaterial/angular-material-router-outlet/